# Login Form - Not working

Tags: vb.net, forms, authentication

Struggling with creating a login from a text file database. The information needs to be manually entered into the text file before it works... see my code below for the form. Its not letting me login.

```
Public Class UserLogin
    Private PWD As String
    Public User As User
    Public Users As List(Of User) = New List(Of User)

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            If isValidData() Then

                If isValidUser() Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")
                    Form2.Show()
                    Me.Hide()

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or password")
                End If
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.GetType.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, "User Does not Exist")

        End Try

    End Sub
    Private Function isValidData() As Boolean

        Return Validator.IsPresent(TextBox1, "Username") AndAlso
        Validator.IsPresent(TextBox2, "Password")

    End Function
    Private Function isValidUser() As Boolean

        Return UserDB.ValidateUser("Username", "Password")


    End Function
    Public Sub setPath(cwd As String)
        PWD = cwd
    End Sub
End Class
```

User class below :

```
Public Class User
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(Username As String, Password As String)
        Me.Username = Username
        Me.Password = Password


    End Sub

    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String



    Public Function GetDisplayText(sep As String) As String
        Dim text As String = Username & sep & Password
        Return text

    End Function
End Class
```

UserDB class Below

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class UserDB
    Private Const Databasename = "C:\Depreciate\Users.txt"
    Public User As New User
    Public Shared Users As List(Of User) = New List(Of User)


    Public Shared Function GetUsers(Dir As String) As List(Of User)
        Dim Users As New List(Of User)
        Dim textIn As New StreamReader(
            New FileStream(Databasename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))



        Do While textIn.Peek <> -1
            Dim row As String = textIn.ReadLine
            Dim columns As String() = row.Split(CChar(","))
            Dim User As New User
            User.Username = columns(0)
            User.Password = columns(1)
            Users.Add(User)

        Loop
        textIn.Close()


        Return Users
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ValidateUser(username As String, password As String) As Boolean

        Dim Validated = False

        For Each userEntry As User In Users


            If username = userEntry.Username AndAlso password = userEntry.Password Then
                Validated = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return Validated


    End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you compare all user names and passwords to the strings "Username" and "Password" by calling:

```
Return UserDB.ValidateUser("Username", "Password")
```

in `isValidUser`.Probably you should better pass the actual username and the password which the user has typed instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code: 
First I can't see anywhere the call to `UserDB.GetUsers` that should initialize the list of users from the file. But also assuming that you have made the call in some other place, there is another problem in that method.

This line inside the GetUsers method creates a new variable of type List(Of User) and name it with the same name of the Shared one effectively hiding the one declared at the global class level

```
 Dim Users As New List(Of User)
```

Then your code continue and fills a variable named Users but this variable is not the shared one declared at the class global level. Of course, when you search your username and password in the shared variable you don't find anything.

Just remove that line and let the call To GetUsers fill the same variable used in the check

(Of course I also assume that when you call UserDB.ValidateUser you will pass an actual Username and a password and not the placeholders string that you are using in the code above)

Comment: Thanks buddddd got itt!!!!!! removed that line and created a line inside the button click function that gets the users.